# Using openpyxl module to write to spreadsheet creates a damaged spreadsheet, how to fix with zipfile module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl, python-zipfile

I have a program which writes to a spreadsheet using `openpyxl`. Upon execution of the program, the cells are filled as expected but the spreadsheet becomes damaged. Excel repairs the spreadsheet and I can then view it again.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
amounts, row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2
book = load_workbook("output.xlsx")
sheet = book.active

for i, value in enumerate(amounts):
    sheet.cell(column=i+1, row=row, value=value)  
print ("Sheet updating complete.")
book.save("output.xlsx")
```

I have tried using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool from Microsoft to compare a good and bad file with each other and noticed that `styles.xml` is missing. I try to copy this over using the following source code I have obtained from another question, but it does not solve the issue for me.

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('outputcopy.xlsx', 'r') as zgood:
    styles_xml = zgood.read('xl/styles.xml')
with zipfile.ZipFile('output.xlsx', 'a') as zbad:
    zbad.writestr('xl/styles.xml', styles_xml)
```

I can confirm from the repair log Excel generates, that the problem is with `xl/styles.xml`. I need to copy this xml file from the good copy, to the bad copy.

How can I get the `xl/styles.xml` file copied so that the program can run without damaging `output.xlsx`?

I have made another attempt to fix this issue. In the off chance that `styles.xml` cannot be copied from a different Excel file; I have opened `styles.xml` from `output.xlsx` prior to `book.save("output.xlsx")`. After saving, I then get the `styles.xml` from before the save statement, and write it. Unfortunately, this has not changed anything and I am still getting a damaged Excel file. With this attempt, my test code looks like this:

```
import openpyxl
import zipfile

from openpyxl import load_workbook
amounts, indexValue, row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, 2
book = load_workbook("output.xlsx")
sheet = book.active

for i, value in enumerate(amounts):
    sheet.cell(column=i+1, row=row, value=value)  
print ("Sheet updating complete.")

with zipfile.ZipFile('output.xlsx', 'r') as zgood:
    styles_xml = zgood.read('xl/styles.xml')

book.save("output.xlsx")

with zipfile.ZipFile('output.xlsx', 'a') as zbad:
    zbad.writestr('xl/styles.xml', styles_xml)
```

I have tried saving as a completely new Excel File, but still have the same issue. I tried using `zip file` to open from `output.xlsx` and writing to the newly saved file, but still no result.

```
import openpyxl
import zipfile
from openpyxl import load_workbook

amounts, indexValue, row, cell = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, 2, "A2"
book = load_workbook("output.xlsx")
sheet = book.active

while indexValue != 5:
    sheet[cell] = amounts[indexValue]
    indexValue += 1
    cell = chr(ord(cell[0]) + 1) + str(cell[1])
print ("Sheet updating complete.")

book.save("test.xlsx")

with zipfile.ZipFile('output.xlsx', 'r') as zgood:
    styles_xml = zgood.read('xl/styles.xml')
with zipfile.ZipFile('test.xlsx', 'a') as zbad:
    zbad.writestr('xl/styles.xml', styles_xml)
```

Although I have already fixed this issue, it is worth noting that this problem only seems to occur when loading a workbook. I have created another program with spreadsheets that creates a workbook, rather than loading it. As a result of this, the spreadsheet does not saves damaged.

Comment: What version of Microsoft Excel are you using? I'm using MS Excel 2010 and it shows no errors using your example.

Comment: @Brian I am using the latest versions of Microsoft Excel, 2016. I have tried opening the Excel file on both OS X and Windows 10. On a side note, Apple's Numbers seems to be able to open to the file perfectly fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After confirming that the issue was with `styles.xml`, I identified that the issue was most likely with the style formatting of the written cells. By using `styles` from the `openpyxl` module, I have fixed the issue.

I declare a variable, `fontStyle` in this case, and set all the style settings:

```
fontStyle = Font(name="Calibri", size=12, color=colors.BLACK)
```

When writing `amounts` to each cell, I also set the style of these cells using `fontStyle`:

```
sheet[cell].font = fontStyle
```

The completed code, looks like this:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color

fontStyle = Font(name="Calibri", size=12, color=colors.BLACK)
amounts, indexValue, cell = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, "A2"
book = load_workbook("output.xlsx")
sheet = book.active

while indexValue != 5:
    sheet[cell] = amounts[indexValue]
    sheet[cell].font = fontStyle
    indexValue += 1
    cell = chr(ord(cell[0]) + 1) + str(cell[1])

print ("Sheet updating complete.")
book.save("output.xlsx")
```

I believe this has worked because the writing method has no default style settings. This would explain why `styles.xml` was missing when using the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool. Upon checking this Excel file again after the fix, I can confirm that `styles.xml` is no longer missing.

The file is no longer damaged upon being saved and can be opened normally again. Also, I am now able to execute this script to write to the Excel file again, without having to open and close to repair it.

Note that I have also changed my loop from the original loop - as part of one of my attempts to fix the issue. This has not had an effect on the final outcome - it is all down to the styling of the cells written.

This doesn't exactly answer the question of solving the issue specifically with `zipfile` but it does solve the problem.

Comment: what is amounts, index , cell for ?