# openpyxl workbook.save() corrupts simple xlsx workbook with external link

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a  simple Excel xlsx file with one sheet and one external link which becomes corrupted if I open it and save it with openpyxl.

This is a question similar to others ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59308064/openpyxl-workbook-save-function-creates-a-corrupt-and-un-openable-excel-xlsx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925006/using-openpyxl-module-to-write-to-spreadsheet-creates-a-damaged-spreadsheet-how) and elsewhere).  However, my example does not contain complicated excel features like charts / images / macros.  And my example is not solved by different versions of openpyxl.
I have tested these versions of openpyxl:

- 3.0.3
- 2.4
- 3.1.1
- 3.1.2

I have a  simple Excel file with one sheet.  It has one formula which is a link to another workbook. The formula is:

`='C:\Temp\temp\[Book2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$3`

Now I run the simple program:

```
def main():
    f1="C:/Temp/temp/Book1.xlsx"
    print(openpyxl.__version__)
    wb=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=f1)
    wb.save(f1)
    wb.close()
```

After I run this the file becomes corrupted:

[image]

If I allow Excel to attempt to recover the file, the external link appears as:
`=[RecoveredExternalLink1]Sheet1!$A$3`

I can update this link  to the original file and no other corruption appears to have occurred.

This problem seems to have happened recently.  Similar code I have been using for over a year has started to produce this issue in the last couple of months.  My version of Excel (64 bit) is:

[image]